# Can you recommend a data grid class/gem for Ruby on Rails that supports dynamic column selection?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I'm looking for a rails gem (or possibly several together) that will be the basis of the user facing front end for my application.

I'm constraint by a few things -

First, my user base is very technically challenged.  All of the UI pieces have to be very easy to understand (in other words they've been seen a lot).  It will be a stretch for these users to click on a column header and expect it to sort without some kind of prompting.

Second, the application flow needs to be very simple.  As I mentioned in the first condition if I spread this out into a lot of small actions I'm likely to loose my user.

The core of the problem is that I have a dataset with 15 columns.  I'd like to have the ability to:

- have the users dynamically select which columns to view at one time
- sort on any column in the view
- filter the results (via text and attribute search)
- pagination

I don't need any editing capabilities.

I've googled around for "ruby on rails datagrid" without much luck.  I'm developing on Rails 3.1.  Thank you for any help!

Comment: Another important piece I forgot to mention here is that my attributes exist across 3 different models.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the rails-casts on doing this with using the will_paginate gem and some sorting code: http://railscasts.com/episodes/240-search-sort-paginate-with-ajax and http://railscasts.com/episodes/228-sortable-table-columns

Comment: There's also an incredible one on in-place editing you may want to combine with it: http://railscasts.com/episodes/302-in-place-editing

Answer (score 0):

I'd take a look at [DataTables](http://www.datatables.net/). It's a JS table and there are some ruby gems that wrap it, e.g.: [jquery-datatables-rails](https://github.com/rweng/jquery-datatables-rails). There is also a [railscast about it](http://railscasts.com/episodes/340-datatables).

Answer (score 0):

Try [Datagrid](https://github.com/bogdan/datagrid) - ruby library that helps you to build and represent table-like data with:

- Customizable filtering
- Columns
- Sort order
- Localization
- Export to CSV